# how to make sure counter atomic by using redis incr command

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I'm using redis `incr` as our request counter as I researched `incr` is a atomic and thread-safe, now I wanna add `expire` time for each key but seems this process is not thread-safe, for example, redis crash only after `incr` done and before `Expire` command running, the basic pseudocode is as below:

```
value := redisClient.getValue(key)
if value > common.ChatConfig.SendMsgRetryCfg.RetryCount {
      return error
}
value, err := redisClient.Incr(key).Result()
if err == nil {
    redisClient.Expire(key, 24*time.Hour)
}
```

I wanna know how to change my codes and make the process be atomic and thread-safe? thank u

Comment: What do you mean by "redis crash"?

Comment: @GuyKorland I mean between `Incr` command and  `expire` command, redis doesn't work maybe caused by redis cluster issues, network issues and so on, that will make key expire time be forever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the two commands "atomic" use a [Redis transaction](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) or a [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval). This will be thread-safe and fault-tolerant, as any changes will be persisted only after all commands (in the tx/script) had finished.

Comment: oh, let me try it